# PHP: Finding the text between <p>'s

Tags: php

Quick and probably incredibly easy question;

```
$str="<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque turpis risus, rutrum pretium scelerisque nec, sollicitudin ac quam. Nulla eu dolor sapien, id bibendum augue. Aliquam eu nunc mi. Nam consectetur vestibulum leo elementum condimentum. Etiam varius malesuada sapien eget fermentum. Aenean ut massa lacus. Duis non enim enim. </p>
<p>Nam egestas laoreet eros, a mattis dui fringilla ac. Aliquam erat volutpat. Mauris mattis vulputate condimentum. Vivamus libero quam, tincidunt at viverra id, iaculis a tellus. Cras venenatis ante non enim interdum ac adipiscing neque euismod. Pellentesque nec elementum metus.
</p>"
```

I would like to obtain each text between '< p >' tags. Since I'm a beginner php programmer I wanted to ask if there is any easy way before constructing a straight-forward **for** loop.

Comment: This will get you going in the right direction: http://www.phpro.org/examples/Get-Text-Between-Tags.html

Comment: Thank you so much for answering instead of voting down

Comment: yeah, I guess it should be impossible to vote down without any comment...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Always use proper HTML/XML parsing, like [DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

For example :

```
$p = array();
$doc = new Domdocument;
$doc->loadHTML($str);
foreach( $doc->getElementsByTagName("p") as $entry)
{
  $p[] = $entry->nodeValue;
}
// $p will be the array contains each p contents
```

Answer (score 0):

You could e.g. solve this with a [perl regular expression matching](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

```
<?php
preg_match('/<p>(.+)</p>/', $str, $matches);
?>
```

`$matches[1]` will contain everything between the tags. Please note, that this will have not the results you want if your string has several tags, as the later tag will be queried from the end of the string and not from the front.

Comment: Thank you so much for posting this Lars. However I got this error = **Unknown modifier '(' in /Library/WebServer/Documents/temp/index.php on line 15**. Is it because of me being not too careful with syntax or something else?

Comment: my bad - forgot the slashes. However, jeroen's solution will work better, although I believe it will be slower.

Answer (score 0):

You can go for a DOM solution like @ajreal mentioned (I would not recommend regex), but if your string contains new-lines after each paragraph, you can also [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) on the new-lines and then use [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) to get rid of the tags.

The DOM solution is more bullet-proof.